# React quill in nextjs and typescript custom image handler issue?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-quill, react-quilljs

I am try to use `react-quill` in my typescript nextjs project. Here I am finding typing and `ref` issue that I can't solve. Please help me.

Here is code example-

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
const ReactQuill = dynamic(import('react-quill'), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
})
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';


const Editor = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const quillRef = useRef<any>();

    const imageHandler = async () => {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
        input.click();
        input.onchange = async () => {
            var file: any = input && input.files ? input.files[0] : null;
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", file);
            let quillObj = quillRef.current.getEditor();

        };
    }

    const modules = {
        toolbar: {
            container: [
                [{ font: [] }, { 'size': [] }, { 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }],
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
                [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
                [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
                [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }, 'blockquote', 'code-block'],
                [
                    { list: 'ordered' },
                    { list: 'bullet' },
                    { indent: '-1' },
                    { indent: '+1' },
                ],
                [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }, { 'align': [] }],
                ['link', 'image', 'clean'],
            ],
            'handlers': {
                image: imageHandler
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <Container maxWidth="xxxl" disableGutters>
            <ReactQuill
                ref={quillRef} // Here I am finding an issue.
                value={value}
                modules={modules}
                onChange={setValue}
                placeholder="Start typing!"
            />
        </Container>
    );
};



export default Editor;
```

[image]

Here is CodeSandBox-

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-hill-xkb1pj

Can any one give me a proper typescript solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";

const quillRef = useRef<ReactQuill | null>(null);
```